# ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'MY_TABLESPACENAME'

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I'm having this issue when I'm trying to create a partition in Oracle 11g r2, I followed the recommendations of the others post here:

```
grant CONNECT, RESOURCE to dbadmin;

ALTER USER dbadmin QUOTA 100M ON MY_TABLESPACENAME

GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO dbadmin
```

I have granted the privileges to dbadmin, the table that I want to create is for that owner, I have tried with sys too.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure this issue is related to privileges? What error message are you receiving?

Comment: It might help if you posted complete SQLPlus session. It is unclear what user you are currently connected to, what commands you ran and how Oracle responded to each of them.

Comment: the error is this: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace "MY_TABLESPACENAME"

Comment: the command is just this: ALTER TABLE DBADMIN.MY_TABLENAME ADD PARTITION JAN2018 VALUES LESS
THAN(TO_DATE('2018-02-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')) TABLESPACE MY_TABLESPACENAME; with the dbadmin and sys users

Comment: Any luck with this?  I'm hitting the same issue on 12c.  I could create the table in that tablespace, but not insert into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem viewing the DDL of my table, one index have a different owner of the table

Comment: I had the same problem. an index was running on the table from a different owner. solve it by setting unlimited tablespace for that owner.

Comment: wow what luck, perfect situation for me, saved my skin today, 1 heck of an upvote. The schemas were named  similar but not the same but I couldn't see it till this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and to solve that I needed a user that matched the tablespace name with the grants and alters you have listed for that user.  So for your example, you need a MY_TABLESPACENAME user.  You can still use dbadmin to do the work.